# PHP passing value to MySQL stored procedure call getting error Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param()

Tags: php, mysql, call

I'm scratching my head on the PHP to MySQL stored procedure problem, i have a stored procedure in MySQL that awaits for two input parameters. I'm trying to calling the procedure from my PHP code by pass them 2 variables that the php page received via a HTML form. But I kept getting below error:

PHP Warning:  Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in /var/www/html/admin.php on line 26, referer:..... admin.php
 PHP Warning:  mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/html/admin.php on line 27, referer: http://...../admin.php

My PHP code looks like below, which i can find no clue why it fails:

```
 <?PHP  
    if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {
        $ServerSet = $_POST['ServerSet'];
        $Time = $_POST['Time'];

        if ( (strcasecmp ($ServerSet, 'A') == 0) Xor (strcasecmp ($ServerSet, 'B') == 0) ) {
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "appm";
                $password = "appm";
                $dbname = "ITD_infra";

                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

            if (empty($Time)) {
                print "Fit A B and Time null";  
                print " Server is $ServerSet";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("call ext_swing_update_v2(?, null)");       
                $stmt->bind_param($ServerSet);
                $stmt->execute() or die("Call fail: ".mysqli_error());
                $conn->close();
            }

            else {
                print "Both time and server not null";
                print " $ServerSet and $Time";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("call ext_swing_update_v2(?,?)");
                $stmt->bind_param($ServerSet, $Time);                 
                $stmt->execute() or die("Call fail: ".mysqli_error());
                $conn->close();
            }
        }
        else {
            print "Server string not match";  
        }
    }

?>
```

```
    <Form Name="form1" method = "POST" Action= "admin.php" >           
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2>  Infra Admin Page </h2>
        <br>
        <b>Give live external server set as A or B below: </b>
        <br>

        <br>
         Server Set:
         <INPUT TYPE = "Text" NAME = "ServerSet">
         <br>
         Time is in format of YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS, HH is 24hr.
        <br>
         Time:    
         <INPUT TYPE = "Text"  NAME = "Time">
         <br>
         <INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name ="Submit1" VALUE ="Login" > 
    </form>

<br>
<br>
```

Comment: typo `Xor` ? try `mysqli_error($conn)` and `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $var1, $var2);` seems much better [DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. Xor is not a typo, it is to avoid both A and B together.  I tried with below code:  $stmt = $conn->prepare("call ext_swing_update_v2(?, null)");       
                    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $ServerSet);
                    $stmt->execute() or die("Call fail: ".mysqli_error());
                    $conn->close(); //Still failed with same error.

Comment: np, just let us know if you found what errors were